# How to store string in array of pointers?

Tags: c

I have this write function

```
char *string_undo[100];

void write()
{
    char str[100];
    int m=0;
    char c;
    printf("\nEnter the string: ");
    while(1)
    {
      c = getchar();
      if(c=='.')
      {
        break;
      }
      str[m] = c;
      m++;
    }
    str[m] = NULL;
   (stack_undo[i]) = str;

}
```

I am trying to store input entered in str to string_undo. It's a 'C' language program so i am having problem with this string assignment. I have tried usign string copy function even its not
working.

The string is not getting saved in stack_undo pointer.

Comment: You didn't show how `i` is defined or incremented. But, I assume you want to change: `(stack_undo[i]) = str;` into `stack_undo[i] = strdup(str);` In your original code, the function will return, and because `str` is on the stack, it will go out of scope and be inaccessible. The `strdup` creates a copy on the heap that persists after the function returns. _Side note:_ `write` is a bad choice for a function name because it conflicts with a standard function.

Comment: Note that [`strdup` is not part of the C standards before C23](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strdup).

Comment: @Prats Why did you declare an array of pointers though the function tries to store only one string? It is unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you @Craig the code is working now.

Comment: @Vlad I was just trying to store string at that point. So, thus I stored only one string for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: @CraigEstey I didn't understand the sentence 'the function will return,  and because str is on the stack, it will go out of scope and be inaccessible. ' will you please explain this.

Comment: @Prats See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack

Answer (score 0):

I have forgot much of my C skills but I think you have some errors in your code:

1.-
`char *string_undo[100];`

In this sentence, you made a table... to store a string in a pointer you can write instead:

`char *string_undo = "";`

for your function write, it's specially important to initialice it to ""

2.-
`char str[100];`

If you want to use pointers, I think you can do:

`char *str = "";`

3.-
`str[m] = NULL;`

I don't know if it's correct, I allways use

`str[m]='\0';`

4.-
`(stack_undo[i]) = str;`

what is "i" variable? It not appears in all the code.. and stack_undo I think you want to write string_undo...  test one of these:

`string_undo = &str;`

I don't know if it's this way or

`string_undo = str;`

Good luck!

Comment: thanks @cavielles
char *string_undo = "";

Is this a way to declare array of pointers?